# Userform not copying data to spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I made a userform in excel VBA and for some reason my values are not copying onto the spreadsheet. The following are the lines of code for writing the data:

```
Dim RowCount as long

RowCount = Worksheets("Request Log").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Request Log").Range("A1")

 .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = DateValue(Me.txtDate.Value)

 .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.BuyerComboBox.Value

 .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.txtItem.Value

 .Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.txtDes.Value

 .Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.txtCost.Value

 .Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.txtQty.Value

 .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = DateValue(Me.txtNeed.Value)

 .Offset(RowCount, 7).Value = Me.ReasonListBox.Value

 .Offset(RowCount, 8).Value = Me.txtDetails.Value

 End With
```

Please help!! Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you step thru the code?

Comment: I tried stepping through the code, but the userform kept executing since that is the first part of the code.

Comment: Can you send the file to me? Much easier to figure this out that way. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: I sent it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this:

```
'RowCount = Worksheets("Request Log").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Request Log")
    RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With


With Worksheets("Request Log").Range("A1")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = DateValue(Me.txtDate.Value)
    .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.BuyerComboBox.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.txtItem.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.txtDes.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.txtCost.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.txtQty.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = DateValue(Me.txtNeed.Value)
    .Offset(RowCount, 7).Value = Me.ReasonListBox.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 8).Value = Me.txtDetails.Value
End With
```